# CATransition NOT working when kCATransitionFromTop

Tags: objective-c, ios

`CATransition` NOT working when subtype is `kCATransitionFromTop`.

```
CALayer *layer = [self.view layer];    
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = @"pageCurl";
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.delegate = self;

if(viewMode == PORTRAIT)
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
else if(viewMode == UPSIDEDOWN)
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
else if(viewMode == RIGHT)
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];    
else if(viewMode == LEFT)
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];

[layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

everything works fine except `kCATransitionFromTop`. (comes from bottom)

I think subtype of `@"pageCurl"` can't be `FromTop`, so the default value (`FromBottom`)

is assigned. Am I right? and is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Did you actually figured this out? I can see that it is from 5 years ago, but I just came across the same problem